# How to run Test class for HDFS?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I want to run a unit test by using hadoop-hdfs-2.9.2-tests.jar in
hadoop-2.9.2/share/hadoop/hdfs.

1.
It didn't work to run the following command:

```
(yarn jar hadoop-2.9.2/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.9.2-tests.jar
TestWriteRead)
```

The error message said that there is no main class name.

2.
I also tried to manually compile the wordcount class and it failed.

```
- javac -classpath ${HADOOP_CLASSPATH} -d
'hdfs-test/TestWriteRead-cp/'
'/home/hduser/hdfs-test/TestWriteRead.java'
- jar -cvf TestRW.jar -c TestWriteRead-cp .
```

but it didn't work.

How can I run the hdfs-tests.jar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check out here the dependencies on [Hadoop 2.9.2](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs-rbf/dependency-analysis.html) if you want to run same examples you can use this:

```
# su - hdfs
$ cd /opt/yarn/hadoop-2.9.2/bin
$ export YARN_EXAMPLES=/opt/yarn/hadoop-2.9.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce
$ ./yarn jar $YARN_EXAMPLES/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.9.2.jar pi 16 1000
```

There are a big list of examples to run included wordcount, a map/reduce program that counts the words in the input files. You can list it:

```
yarn jar $YARN_EXAMPLES/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar
```

If the path is not the same just run:

```
 $ find / -name "hadoop-mapreduce-examples*.jar" -print
```